# setting the resizing and cropping options correctly

Tags: imageresizer

I am using your resizer tool, it works very well, I am stuck at one place and need your suggestion to help me choose the correct image resizer settings

Everythings works fine when image is smaller than the browser window size I got problem when it's bigger than browser window

I am using the following parameters
orig.jpg?width=1600&height=530&mode=crop&scale=downsizeonly

for example consider a portrait image scenario given below
Browser window size = 1600 Width x 530 height
Original Image size = 1024 Width x 768 height

expected result: 1024 width x 530 height (so it should crop the remaining height)
actualt result: 1600 with x 530 height

Height and its cropping is ok but 1600 width is wrong I want it to be 1024 width so image didn't loose quality

Vise versa functionality I need for Landscape image

What parameter should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The automatic cropping can cause upscaling even when &scale=down IF the requested dimensions would normally NOT cause upscaling with &mode=max or &mode=pad.

This is a known bug that will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: Please help to vote to close the question as "cannot reproduce".